# Printing shadow letters every few inches

Tags: printer

I have a Canon MG5450 and it started to print very odd.

[image]

Every few inches it prints shadow / double letters.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your printer needs re-aligning the print heads, this is normally achieved via software that will of come with your printer.

[Instructions on Canon site for how to re-align printheads](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART141583)

Basically the steps are:

1. Open the printer driver setup window.
2. Click Custom Settings on the Maintenance tab.
3. Switch head alignment to manual.
4. Check the Align heads manually check box.
5. Click OK and when the confirmation message appears, click OK.
6. Click Print Head Alignment on the Maintenance tab.
7. Load three sheets of A4 size or Letter size plain paper into the cassette (lower).
8. Make sure that the machine is on and click Align Print Head.
9. Check the printed pattern.
10. Enter the numbers of the patterns with the least amount of streaks in the associated boxes.
11. The second pattern is printed.
12. Enter the numbers of the patterns with the least amount of streaks in the associated boxes.
13. The third pattern is printed.
14. When you have entered all the necessary values, click OK.

Comment: I have tried it but no change....i did cleaning, then deep cleaning, then print head alignment and nothing.... BUT there is one strange thing....when I put A4 paper to copy it prints it out perfectly....no shadow letters...how can that be? I just don't get it. Only printing documents has problem with letters.